# Perl - Replace all but last occurence

Tags: perl

I have a string which contains multiple occurrences of the string `<br />`.   I want to replace all of those, except the last one, without the slash: `<br>`

So, if I have a string:

```
A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />.
```

I want to have the string:

```
A<br>B<br>C<br>D<br />.
```

Comment: So, if I have a string:  A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />.   I want to have the string:  A<br>B<br>C<br>D<br />.

Comment: Is the last occurrence always at the end of the string?

Comment: The character `/` is a slash, not a backslash. A backslash is \.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion, that requires the string to have at least one `<br />` left: `(?=.*<br />)`. Here is an example:

```
$ perl -pe's|<br />(?=.*<br />)|<br>|g'
A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />
A<br>B<br>C<br>D<br />
```